# Pause a loop Till a button action - Java

Tags: java, loops, button, sleep

I'm making a game like "Who wants to be billionaire?" 
My difficulty is that, I want to Pause  a loop till user press the bottom to commit the answer.
If user press the "commit" button, my frame must be refresh and the next question must be taken place.

I read all posts (with answers thread.sleep()) on Stackoverflow but  I am unable to find good result on my game!

Moreover I want a loop because I don't know any other way to refresh Question on my Frame.

Comment: post some code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop is the wrong way to do it, period. You must replace the loop with an object. Change all local variables used in the loop into instance variables of the object. Define a method on the object which will be called each time you want to "unpause the loop". The method will execute all the code that you currently execute in a single loop iteration.